# Downloaded file is not visible until refreshing the folder

Tags: jquery, download

```
$('#btnDownload').click(function() {
    window.location.href = 'uploads/' + fileName;
});
```

This code downloads a file but the file is not visible inside Downloads folder (win xp) until refreshing it (or enter inside another folder and come back).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the bottom of the file list, where XP will put files added after the folder has loaded. While the file downloads, it is saved to a temporary directory. See more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporary_Internet_Files

Comment: Jervelund, how can I get the file visible in Downloads folder as it is visible if it is downloaded form any url on the web ? It is not visible only using the above script.

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference for Windows Explorer. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome 31. In Firefox works well.

Comment: How does Explorer behave when you download in Chrome and how does it behave when downloading in FF?

Comment: In FF the file is visible without refreshing windows explorer. Using Chrome I must refresh it (f 5) to make the downloaded file visible.

Comment: Jervelund, it seems ok. I see now that the problem exists only when working in localhost. Downloading form the remote server - the file is visible without refreshing. Thanks a lot for your time.